# Origin of "I kid you not"

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the phrase "I kid you not"?

And, on a related note, is the sentence,

> Can't I kid you?

or

> Can't I kid with you?

incorrect?

Comment: "I kid you not." What a man says, while displaying a condom, to assure his future lover he is prepared to prevent pregnancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a print reference of the phrase as early as 1948 in the [International Stereotypers' and Electrotypers' Union Journal, Volume 43](http://books.google.com/books?id=VX81AQAAIAAJ&q=%22kid%20you%20not%22&dq=%22kid%20you%20not%22&hl=en&ei=PFGcTcf3D4mGtwfAseCtBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBjgo):

> Boy!, Oh Boy! I said I asked for a headache when I volunteered for this job, and I kid you not when I repeat it.

But it seems it was given a much wider audience as a phrase spoken several times by [Lieutenant Commander Philip Francis Queeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Queeg) in Herman Wouk's 1951 Pulitzer Prize winning novel, *[The Caine Mutiny](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0316955108)*:

> That's the Navy for you. Pass the buck and get a receipt. Act at discretion, hey? Well that's exactly what I'm going to do, and I kid you not.

Answer (score 5):

[This link](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/27/messages/1090.html) seems ambiguous about the origin, but seems to be popularized by TV show host Jack Parr

> : : I KID YOU NOT - Catchphrase used
>   by Jack Paar. Paar, host of the
>   Tonight Show from 1957 to 1962,
>   'invented the talk-show format as we
>   know it: the ability to sit down and
>   make small talk big,' said Merv
>   Griffin.  'Even youngsters sent to bed
>   before Mr. Paar came on parroted his
>   jaunty catchphrase, 'I kid you not.'
>   From "He invented late-night talk,
>   then walked away," an article in the
>   Herald-Leader, Lexington, Ky., January
>   28, 2004.

Grammatically both your versions are correct -  "kid you" and "kid with you"

Your wording of the question suggests someone is upset about a joke you've played on them, so it's more common to say

*"Just kidding"* rather than pose it as a question.

Comment: +1 for the Jack Paar reference. His catch phrase has evolved to the present-day "I shit you not!"

Answer (score 2):

Google books shows that

> I'm not kidding,

used in the same sense as it is in America today, appears in the British novel *A Daughter of the Philistines* by Leonard Merrick (1897) and in the British novel *The Story of the Amulet* by Edith Nesbit (1906). All Jack Paar did was invert the word order to get *I kid you not.*

Merriam-Webster says that kid (used in this way) is a transitive verb, so the correct American usage is

> I'm kidding you.

or

> I'm not kidding.

Because the verb is transitive,

> Can't I kid with you.

would be incorrect because of the *with* (and it definitely sounds wrong to me). On the other hand, you can say

> Can't I kid around with you.

According to the other answers, the expression seems to have died out in Britain.

Answer (score 1):

I always thought this phrase originated from young goats.  Young goats are called, kids.  These creatures are very playful.  A joke is playful and fun, as are kids.  Hence, "kidding" equates to the act of being playful.

Comment: this is pure speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Your two sentences would not sound correct in British English - they may be grammatically correct, but would not be used. In fact I can't actually tell what they are supposed to mean.

You could kid someone - if you mean to fool someone - but you would use the word 'fool' as kid is not used that way.