# I Kid You not - Word Order

Tags: word-order

I have already asked about whether we can put *not* at the end where it would normally be put right after the auxiliary, and, as I've understood, we cannot normally do that. However, I've heard the expression *I kid you not* lots of times, and I just want you to tell me whether it's just a set expression and, therefore, an exception of that rule.

Comment: You might like to add [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+kid+you+not) to your bookmarks.

Comment: *I kid you not!* is a "set expression / fixed phrase / [catchphrase](https://www.bookofthrees.com/i-kid-you-not/)". Don't copy it in other contexts. As someone says on [wordreferrence](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/negation-without-do.1303619/): *In common conversation, using the simple present rather than the emphatic present would be exceedingly archaic. Other than in poetry, this form is generally not used by anyone who is less than 350 years old.*

Comment: Origins on US television - Jack Paar and Johnny Carson had late night shows in the mid-1900s and often used this expression. It was originally a joke, because _kid_ in the sense of _fool_ is modern usage, whereas the syntax with the final _not_ was archaic, so putting them together is like saying "Dost thou grok it?". Eventually it got to be a trademark phrase for them.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19678/origin-of-i-kid-you-not which relates the origins of "I Kid You Not." It is a deliberately archaic word order, fear not.